# How to prove the product of k consecutive integers greater than k is divisible by a prime greater than k.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Sylvester's theorem :
Bertrand's postulate was proposed for applications to permutation groups. Sylvester (1814–1897) generalized the weaker statement with the statement: the product of k consecutive integers greater than k is divisible by a prime greater than k. Bertrand's (weaker) postulate follows from this by taking k = n, and considering the k numbers n + 1, n + 2, up to and including n + k = 2n, where n > 1. According to Sylvester's generalization, one of these numbers has a prime factor greater than k. Since all these numbers are less than 2(k + 1), the number with a prime factor greater than k has only one prime factor, and thus is a prime. Note that 2n is not prime, and thus indeed we now know there exists a prime p with n < p < 2n.         ——wiki
But how to prove this?

Comment: I want to make sure that I understand. You want to show that for any fixed $k$ and $n > k$, the number $n \cdot \cdots \cdot (n + k - 1)$ is divisible by a prime $p > k$. Is that right?

Comment: From this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128949/strengthening-the-sylvester-schur-theorem) there is a link to one of Erdös's early works, a short self-contained proof of Sylvester's theorem: https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes,I want to show that any fixed k and n>k, the number n⋅⋯⋅(n+k−1) is divisible by a prime p>k